# Is '/api/me' the correct way to return whether a user is authenticated, or is there other recommended ways?

Tags: reactjs

I am using jwt's inside httpOnly cookies for authentication and authorization in my backend.

I have a dynamic route in my React app, `mywebsite.com/users/:username` , where a user can go to another users profile and view their public profile information. Of course fetching and displaying the data of the profile they are doing is done inside a `useEffect` hook when you go to the page.

However I am not sure what is the recommended or go to way to fetching or checking if the user is signed in/verified. I want to check this because I would like to give logged in users abilities to like and follow anyone they want. Of course for any of these actions like like or follow, I would be doing backend verification checks to verify they are who they are and can do what they want to do.

But not sure how to check or store their authenticated/logged in status on the client.

I have thought of two ways of doing this, and am not sure what the "go-to" way most developers choose to implement this

1. I've seen people implement a special api route like `/api/me` that a user sends a get request to, and the response returns whether the user is verified or not. Something like a simple object returning the id of the user if verified or null if not. The way I would implement this is alongside the `useEffect` that fetches the profile info of whatever profile page they are on, theres another `useEffect` that does a GET request to `/api/me` and stores it in a state on the client like `[authUser, setAuthUser]`
2. The second method I thought could work is on the initial get request that fetches the profile data the user is viewing, the response object that returns all the public user data to display that also includes a property called `isAuthenticated` which sends back the id of the authenticated user and null or false if not.

I know in the world of programming there is no "golden path", but I am sure developers have come across so many of the same issues or questions that there is a more accepted way of doing this.

The first one makes the user do two get requests for retrieving the data of the user they are viewing and for verifying if they are authenticated or not. Which makes me lean towards the second option, but it just feels "wrong"

How do you guys implement something like this? Which is the more standard way of doing about this

Comment: How do you determine (server-side) if an API call come from an authenticated used? You first check (for example) for the `Authorization` header and then validate its token. It's sent by the client then the client _knows_ if it has been authenticated or not.

Comment: Hi yes, I am doing the jwt verification on the api calls that should be checking authentication and authorization

I guess my question really is if I should make an entirely new api route to determine if the user is signed in to display appropriate things in my UI, or if I should include a property telling me if the user is authenticated alongside any GET requests, for example fetching data of another users profile

Comment: You don't need to, if the client is sending that header (I assume you control the code where those API calls are made) then the client _knows_ it's authenticated (things might be slightly more complicate than this but whatever library you're using to manage the auth client will also give you what all you need)